# unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'list' and 'int' in pyhton

Tags: python, list, int, word2vec

I have some problems with the code, which he can't process data lists and int.
but at first he was able to produce csv data on line 27 ... but then it can't ...
what's wrong with  hasil=total/kata

```
import gensim
#import pandas as  pd
import re
import csv
import numpy as np
def processing(kata):
    words=re.sub(r'([^\s\w]|_)', '', kata)
    words= re.sub(r'[0-9]+', '', words)
    return words
def data():
    path = './model_terbaru/idwiki_word2vec_100.model'
    model = gensim.models.word2vec.Word2Vec.load(path)
    fp = open('data/data_train.csv', 'r')
    line = fp.readline()
    while line:
        processed = processing(line)
        print (processed)
        kata=len(processed.split())
        print(kata)
        total=[100]
        print(total)
        for word in processed.split():
            try:
                vector=model[""+word+""]
                print(vector)
                total=total+vector
                print(word)
            except:
                pass
        hasil=total/kata
        print(hasil)
        mylist= hasil 
        ok=open('data/vector_train.csv','a')
        a=csv.writer(ok,lineterminator='\n')
        a.writerows([mylist])
        ok.close()
        line = fp.readline()
    fp.close()

data()
```

hasil=total/kata
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'list' and 'int'

please help me.

Comment: `total=[100]` - Why is this a list?

Comment: `total` is a list: `[100]`. What do you expect `total/kata` to do?

Comment: Unrelated: why do you rwite `[""+word+""]` instead of just `[word]`?

Comment: You can simplify the loop to `for line in fp:`

Comment: Don't open the output file every time through the loop. Open it once, then append to it each time through the loop.

Comment: And instead of `ok.writerows([mylist])` use `ok.writerow(mylist)`. There's no need to add another level of list nesting.

Comment: total must list because of the ['word'] model in the form of a list. so I add each word in the sentence, then divided by the number of words

Comment: when I use writerow the results remain the same as unsupported operand type (s) for /: 'list' and 'int'

Comment: for normal list you have to divde every element separatelly using `for` loop or list comprehension - ie. `total = [x/kata for x in total]`. If you will use numpy array or pandas dataframe then you can divide `list/integer`

Comment: when I use total = [x / word for x in total] remains error ZeroDivisionError: division by zero. if i want to use numpy array or pandas dataframe. how to implement it in my code

Comment: if word is zero then you have `x/0`. You have to check word and divide only when it is not zero.

Comment: if i use numpy array or pandas dataframe in my code.. can u help me

Comment: converting list `[100, 200, 300]` to numpy array `arr = np.array( [100, 200, 300] )` and now you can divide by integer - ie. divide by 2 `arr = arr/2`. But still you have to check if you don't divide by zero.

Answer (score 0):

```
 for word in processed.split():
    #for line in fp:
        try:
            vector=model[""+word+""]
            print(vector)
            total=total+vector
            print(word)
        except:
            pass
    if kata is not 0 :
        hasil = [x/kata for x in total]
    #hasil=total/kata
        print(hasil)
        mylist= hasil 
        ok=open('data/vector_train.csv','a')
        a=csv.writer(ok,lineterminator='\n')
        a.writerow([mylist])
        line = fp.readline()
        ok.close()
    else:
        print('tes')
```

now my code is like this but the continuous word is considered 0